# Merge two Json Schemas

Tags: jsonschema

I am new to JSON and JSON schema validation.

I have the following schema to validate a single employee object:

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
    "title":"Employee Type Schema",
    "type":"object",
    "properties": 
    {
        "EmployeeID": {"type": "integer","minimum": 101,"maximum": 901,"required":true},
        "FirstName": {"type": "string","required":true},
        "LastName": {"type": "string","required":true},
        "JobTitle": {"type": "string"},
        "PhoneNumber": {"type": "string","required":true},
        "Email": {"type": "string","required":true},
        "Address": 
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": 
            {
                "AddressLine": {"type": "string","required":true},
                "City": {"type": "string","required":true},
                "PostalCode": {"type": "string","required":true},
                "StateProvinceName": {"type": "string","required":true}
            }
        },
        "CountryRegionName": {"type": "string"}
    }
}
```

and I have the following schema to validate an array of the same employee object:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
    "title": "Employee set",
    "type": "array",
    "items": 
    {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": 
        {
            "EmployeeID": {"type": "integer","minimum": 101,"maximum": 301,"required":true},
            "FirstName": {"type": "string","required":true},
            "LastName": {"type": "string","required":true},
            "JobTitle": {"type": "string"},
            "PhoneNumber": {"type": "string","required":true},
            "Email": {"type": "string","required":true},
            "Address": 
            {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": 
                {
                    "AddressLine": {"type": "string","required":true},
                    "City": {"type": "string","required":true},
                    "PostalCode": {"type": "string","required":true},
                    "StateProvinceName": {"type": "string","required":true}
                }
            },
            "CountryRegionName": {"type": "string"}
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please show me how to merge them so that way I can use one single schema to validate both single employee object or an entire collection. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*(Note: this question was also asked on the [JSON Schema Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/json-schema/t36oRQdDJ7I/HeuE2RhRLHoJ), and this answer is adapted from there.)*

With "`$ref`", you can have something like this for your array:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {"$ref": "/schemas/path/to/employee"}
}
```

If you want something to be an array or a single item, then you can use "`oneOf`":

```
{
    "oneOf": [
        {"$ref": "/schemas/path/to/employee"}, // the root schema, defining the object
        {
            "type": "array", // the array schema.
            "items": {"$ref": "/schemas/path/to/employee"}
        }
    ]
}
```

The original Google Groups answer also contains some advice on using `"definitions"` to organise schemas so all these variants can exist in the same file.

Comment: this answer is not about merging the schemas, not related to the question asked

Comment: The title is quite general, but the body of the question asks for "one single schema to validate both single employee object or an entire collection", and that's what the answer gives.